# How to change a child’s Wi-Fi network remotely?

Tags: wi-fi, google-family-link

Our Wi-Fi hasn’t worked right since a day or two after the Xfinity guy left, it connects “strong” but has no internet. We have been searching for my kid’s emergency phone for quite some time, and finally looked in Family Link today. The phone is still at 5%, not sure how it’s not dead. The last ping was Aug 18, but it is connected to a Wi-Fi network that does not seem to let me pull the location or ring it… my guess would be our home internet.

Is there a way to switch it over to a hotspot without having the phone in hand? It should already know the hotspot password. The kid's phone is a Samsung Galaxy S9 if that info helps or is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone's battery registered at 5% 2 months ago, its battery is now depleted.  Sorry.  You are likely looking at stats from the last measurement taken while the phone still had some charge.

Even if it had battery power, I don't think there is a way to change its connectivity.

Your best bet is to observe your offspring's height, and look for hiding places within the reach of someone that height.  Under furniture and beds is a favourite hiding spot for missing phones, as well as between sofa cushions!

Good luck!

P.S. That's a fancy phone for a kid's emergency phone.  If you need to replace it, you'll be able to buy a replacement for a lower cost.